# Segmentation fault with a recursive function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I try to execute this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int byteland(int a)
{
   int e,f,g;
   if ((a/2 + a/3 + a/4) < a)
      return a;
   else
   {
      e = byteland(a/2);
      f = byteland(a/3);
      g = byteland(a/4);
      return e + f + g;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int a, b;
   scanf("%d", &a);
   b = byteland(a);
   return 0;
}
```

I get segmentation fault (core dumped). Any solution?

Comment: Running without problems for me. What's your input ?

Comment: Probably just recursion to deep. How deep is it?

Comment: just curiosity, what does this function do?

Comment: its solution to http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

Answer (score 5):

If you use `0` for `a`, you get infinite recursion -- stack overflow. You also get infinite recursion for many negative numbers.

Not sure what this function is supposed to do but there is nothing to break the recursion when `a` is equal to `0`.

I would add a clause to break the recursion when `a` is equal to `0`.

```
int byteland(int a)
{
   int e,f,g;
   if ( a == 0 )
   {
      return 0;
   }
   else if((a/2+a/3+a/4)<a)
   {
      return a;
   }
   else
   {
      e=byteland(a/2);
      f=byteland(a/3);
      g=byteland(a/4);
      return e+f+g;
   }
}
```